# Show that $f: G \to H $ is a homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is my first encounter with homomorphisms and I'd like to have my proof verified.

Question: Let $G = (\mathbb{Z}, +)$ and $H = \{6^{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. Define $f: G \to H$ by $f(x) = 6^{x}$. Show this is a homomorphism.

Attempt: We want to show $f(a + b) = f(a) \cdot f(b)$ for all $a, b \in G$. We know $f(a+b) = 6^{a + b}$ which is equivalent to $6^{a} \cdot 6^{b}$ by properties of exponents. So we have $f(a) \cdot f(b)$

I could be wrong in what I have to show, would also appreciate what the homomorphism means in this case or in general. Thanks.

Comment: Careful,$a+b \neq a \cdot b$.  But, the general idea is correct.

Comment: I assume it's just a typo when you write $6^{a \cdot b}$ instead of $6^a \cdot 6^b$?

Comment: Typo yes fixed it, other than that is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your proofs looks correct. I wouldn't say that "$\dots = 6^{a+b}$ which is equivalent to $6^a\cdot 6^b$". It isn't that they are *equivalent*, they are in fact *equal*. So maybe you could just write:
$$
f(a + b) = 6^{a + b} = 6^a6^b = f(a)f(b).
$$

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly correct, you've shown what you wanted. It's always worth checking, just as an exercise, that this maps the identity of one group to the identity of the other.

Also note that in this case you have an isomorphism, as there's a pretty straightforward bijection between the two underlying sets.